# Переклад "палочка выручалочка"

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, from-russian

[Google](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=uk&text=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) перекладач подає

> палочка виручалочка

Однак, я невпевнена, що це нормативний переклад. В [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/palychka) стаття "паличка" не мість словосполучення "павличка виручалочка". Натомість є стаття [палочка-стукалочка](http://sum.in.ua/s/palychka-stukalochka)

> Назва дитячої гри, а також дрючечок, дощечка і т. ін., що
>   використовуються у цій грі.

Це не те, що я шукаю.

Як правильно зробити переклад словосполучення "палочка выручалочка" в значені паличка, яка допомагає (як у [казці](https://deti-online.com/skazki/skazki-suteeva/palochka-vyruchalochka/))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [словнику Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf) (ст. 246 ПДФ) бачимо переклад:

> "палочка-выручалочка волшебная" - "**паличка-виручалочка чарівна**"

Українсько-російский і російсько-український фразеологичний словник (Олейник І. С., Сидоренко М. М.) дає ще й варіант "**паличка-стукалочка**" (даремно ви відкидаєте такий варіант перекладу, бо серед [значень](https://phraseology.academic.ru/8257/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) "палочки-выручалочки" є "дитяча гра").

На форумі [словник UA](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t724.html) також розглядали це питання. Окрім наведених вище варіантів там також пропонують "**паличка-рятуваличка**". Але дуже багато варіантів є на сторінці [ЖЖ](https://ua-mova.livejournal.com/775713.html) присвяченій українській мові (звичайно джерело не є 100% надійним, але деякі варінти заслуговують уваги):

**Чарівна паличка**

**Чарівний жезл**

**Патичок-допомогачок** (не знаю чому, але мені такий варіант подобається найбільше)

**Патичок-помагайло**

**Патик-помагай**

Також ще дуже хороший варіант можна знайти в [Російсько-українському народному сучасному словнику](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on):

**Патичок-рятівничок**